# What legal actions should I take to get tuition fees refunded after the school went bankrupt?

Tags: united-kingdom, bankruptcy, tuition, consumer-protection

I applied to the Northern School of Languages in Leeds and my student visitor visa was refused. But the school has gone bankrupt, and the financial case is now handled by the Ferguson Company Ltd. on behalf of the school.

The company told me that I will get only 25% of the full tuition fees I paid as they don't have enough funds and have to share with all the students they have to pay back.

Is there any way I can try to get more than 25%? Can I get all the tuition fees I paid to the school? If so please tell me.  I would also like to know legal actions that I need to take to get my money back.

Comment: 25% actually seems pretty generous in a bankruptcy case. The UK has pretty well defined laws [around the priorities of debtors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Kingdom_insolvency_law#Priorities). Many creditors can expect 10% or less. I'm not sure there is anything you can do about it.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like your visa being refused is entirely irrelevant.

What happens in bankruptcy is that all the assets of the bankrupt entity are taken over, liquidated, and the proceeds are distributed to the creditors. You're one of the creditors, and as you've been told - the proceeds are not enough to pay all the creditors in full. This is quite common in bankruptcies. What you *can* do is sue in court and demand priority over other creditors, but...

a. You're exactly the same as many other creditors (rest of the students), so why would you get a priority?

b. Suing costs money and even if you get more, you'll pay way more for legal fees and expenses.

What else can you do?

If you paid with a credit card - your credit card company *may* be able to reverse charges. Sometimes that works, depending on how fast you move.

If you paid with a check - your bank may similarly be able to stop payment on the check. This provided it hasn't been settled yet.

Comment: Hi @littleadv, someone from the school just replied me from facebook that the school didn't go bankrupt. So is there anyway I can do to get all the tuition fees I paid ? Thank you So much .

Comment: @JjHa Please edit your question to reflect that, it significantly changes the question.

Comment: The *debtors* are repaid? or the *creditors*?

Comment: @ThePhoton nice catch, corrected